# Adapting a Master-Detail Application into SingleView App: problems with AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, master-detail

I'm trying to take a blog reader app that already worked into a new app. The working blog reader app was made as a Master-Detail Application, I'm really trying to understand how these split views work so I added a Split View as part of a single view template and I get an error that I can't really understand, I have been looking online but I can't think of a way to solve this, the error I get is the following:

[image: XcodeError]

And the structure of my project is this one:

[image: MainStoryBoard]

Any ideas what is causing this problem? The code I'm using worked fine without the initial View Controller, just the split view from a Master-Detail Application template.

Comment: Your UISplitViewController will be created only after you tap "Go to Blog" button. At this point of app execution window!.rootViewController is view controller with "Home" title and "Go to Blog" button. So You just trying to force cast UIViewController to UISplitViewController which cause crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this code to another place. Add following method overriding to your view controller with "Home" title and ""Go to Blog" button:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let spleatViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UISplitViewController
    //Do another customization...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the `window!.rootViewController` is the controller with the blue "Go to blog" button. I assume it's not a `UISplitViewController` instance, and that's why you get this crash. I also assume that you can get the instance of the `UISplitViewController` somewhere around the tap handler for the "Go to blog" button, where this controller is being presented.